# Installing qgis2web in qgis3 (2.99) on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: qgis2web, qgis-3

When installing the plugin qgis2web through the plugin manager on the qgis 2.99 nightly release I get the following error message. Does anyone know what I need to do to get it working. I've not seen an obvious corresponding issue on the github repo.

```
Couldn't load plugin 'qgis2web' due to an error when calling its classFactory() method 

ImportError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 336, in startPlugin
    plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
  File "/home/will/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgis2web/__init__.py", line 28, in classFactory
    from .qgis2web import Qgis2Web
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 664, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/home/will/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgis2web/qgis2web.py", line 30, in 
    from qgis2web.maindialog import MainDialog
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 664, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/home/will/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgis2web/maindialog.py", line 55, in 
    from qgis.PyQt.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebView, QWebInspector, QWebPage
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 664, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/qgis/PyQt/QtWebKitWidgets.py", line 26, in 
    from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 664, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ImportError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets'


Python version: 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609] 
QGIS version: 2.99.0-Master Master, 585a4d3 

Python Path:
/home/will/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/gml_application_schema_toolbox/extlibs
/usr/share/qgis/python
/home/will/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python
/home/will/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins
/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins
/usr/lib/python35.zip
/usr/lib/python3.5
/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload
/home/will/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
/home/will/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python
```

Comment: Did you check if you have PyQt5 installed?

Comment: I can run `import PyQt 5` in the python console, but `import PyQt 5.QtWebKitWidgets` throws and error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The missing module is 'PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets' which can be installed on ubuntu as part of the 'python3-pyqt5.qtwebkit' deb package.

To check if it is already installed, and ensure it is available, the command is:

`apt-cache policy python3-pyqt5.qtwebkit`

Assuming it isn't installed, then it can be  installed with:

`sudo apt install python3-pyqt5.qtwebkit`

[@TomChadwin](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/272491/115) put me on the right track.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what distribution you are on, but this is likely to be the availability of QtWebkit, or its Python bindings. See if you can ensure they are installed.

Comment: Thanks Tom. Should this be as part of the qgis install, or should they be somewhere separate? When you say 'distribution' do you mean of qgis2web?

Comment: I believe he<s referring to your Linux distribution or your OS. It may be the case that Ubuntu/CentOS/etc. doesn't include the latest version of QtWebkit5 or include more recent Python bindings for it. This is particularly true for LTS distributions (e.g. Ubuntu Xenial or Debian Jessie).

Comment: Thanks! Slow going with QGIS on ubuntu so appreciate the help. I'm on Ubuntu Xenial, I installed QGIS with `http://qgis.org/ubuntugis-nightly xenial main` and `http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu xenial main` ppa repositories. So assumed they handled dependencies. How would I check for the QtWebKit5/it's python bindings?

Comment: Ok, so this was it. After briefly breaking everything by trying to use `pip` to install the qtwebkit (bad idea), I settled on `$ apt-cache policy python3-pyqt5.qtwebkit` to check if it was installed and then `$ sudo apt install python3-pyqt5.qtwebkit`. I have edited the answer to include these steps.

Comment: So my edit was rejected, which is fine, but perhaps @Tom Chadwin you might want to include those steps. It wasn't immediately obvious to me how to follow your advice as a linux novice.

Comment: I didn't give details because I'm not much of a Linux user either. Your edit would have made it look as though I knew things I don't.

Comment: @RoperMaps think of self-answering your question.